# How to make a request

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have database

```
Table room: id,name
Table table: id, id_room
Table WorkPanel: id, id_table, **date**.
```

I use  (date == date, and WorkPanel have record with table):

```
var nowWorkPanels = from a in context.WorkPanels where a.date == date select a;
```

but I do not understand how to make a check at that time and in this room there is a record

Comment: I don't see a date field in any of the tables.

Comment: You have a table _called_ `table`? I see that leading to some interesting issues later on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously not showing all of the fields in your tables, but if your navigational properties are set up correctly, your query will look something like:

```
from wp in context.WorkPanels
where wp.date == date && wp.Table.id_room == roomId
select wp;
```

or if you want to query by room name:

```
from wp in context.WorkPanels
where wp.date == date && wp.Table.Room.name == roomName
select wp;
```

I prefer the more concise method chaining syntax, though:

```
context.WorkPanels.Where(wp => wp.date == date && wp.Table.id_room == roomId);
```

Comment: good, but I have problem I can not check your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279467/why-null-is-returned