# Why null is returned?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong

Not null:

```
var workPanels = (IEnumerable)context.WorkPanels;
```

Null:

```
var nowWorkPanels = from wp in context.WorkPanels select wp;
```

Why?

Comment: These are two different statements - we'd need to know your application

Comment: Did you step through the code?

Comment: A LINQ query cannot possibly be null. Are you sure you don't mean that the enumeration is empty? Or perhaps that the first item in the enumeration is null? Could you please give us a complete piece of code so that your problem is clear?

Comment: And why are you casting WorkPanels to the old-style `IEnumerable` (non-generic) interface?

Comment: You shouldn't be needing this cast: `(IEnumerable)context.WorkPanels`

Comment: So you accepted the answer that says that the question is wrong?

Comment: @Jeffrey: A LINQ query most definitely can be null. There is nothing preventing you from making your own implementations of Where and Select and so on that return whatever you want. If you're using the standard implementation of LINQ methods provided by Microsoft then the query will never be null.

Comment: It is impossible null was selected when select collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be the case. `from wp in context.WorkPanels select wp;` is equivalent to `context.WorkPanels.Select(wp => wp);`. The MS implementations of `Select` ([`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) / [`Queryable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx)) never return `null`.
There must be something else wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Well, to be picky: *sensible* implementations of Select never return null. Select is usually an extension method; someone could have added an extension method called Select to a static class in the current namespace that always returns null. That would be a dumb thing to do, but it would be perfectly legal C# as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @Eric: Sure. I updated my answer, so it is clear, what I am talking about.

Comment: I am oddly amused by the fact that the accepted answer to this question is basically "your question is wrong". :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Maybe that sent him searching some place else and made him discover the real error? In this case the answer really did help him.